# Salesforce JWT flow fully programatically

Tags: jwt, salesforce

I'm building a server->server salesforce integration tool.

I can use code to produce a JWT correctly - but the first time it connects to salesforce - it gives back a "user hasn't approved this consumer".

I can fix this problem by going and use the salesforce oauth login with the given user and clientId, and any old redirect url - putting in the users's salesforce credentials - and from then on the JWT token works.

However - we have lots of environments - things get changed, refreshed, and we want to be in a world where everything gets set up by a script.

So how do I *programatically* connect the user and client ID?    I tried logging in with the username/password program flow - which correctly gives me back an access token - but it does NOT achieve whatever linkage the manual oauth does.

Comment: This question has been [extensively covered](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/207685/oauth-2-0-jwt-bearer-token-flow-user-hasnt-approved-this-consumer) on [Salesforce SE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com) it's a better forum for very Salesforce-specific questions.

Comment: yeah - looked at that - both options provided are _manual_ options - ie involve a human being clicking something on a salesforce UI.  If we want to setup a stack programatically, that's not an option

Comment: There are Q&As that cover non-programmatic option, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this was painful, but finally figured it out - the magic that is not in any of the documentation is you have to select

```
Perform requests on your behalf at any time (refresh_token, offline_access)
```

in the selected oauth scope.
In "Manage" you select which profiles are allowed to connect to the app, and select a permission set - and then it works, without having to do any individual oauth thing.

Answer (score 1):

We had this problem while trying to access the connected app as a community user. We resolved it with the following steps:

1. Go to **Setup > Manage Connected Apps**.
2. Click on the connected app.
3. Click **Edit Policies**.
4. Set **Permitted Users** to **Admin approved users are pre-authorized**. (We had this part as All users may self-authorize but it wasn't working for community users)
5. Go to the profile you wish to give access.
6. Click **Edit**.
7. In the **Connected App Access** check the checkbox of your connected app.